# Syntax for referencing a Linked SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

EDIT: Disregard this post. Apparently SQL Azure doesn't allow referencing other Databases :\

I have two databases A and B, which are on different servers, and B is on a SQL server S.
B is linked to A.

I am trying to access entries from the id column of Table R in database B and put them in A.

This is incorrect according to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, because I am getting a multi-part identifier could not be bound error:

```
S.B.dbo.R.id
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is to use openquery.  While it's a little harder to write, it runs a lot faster.

Comment: Have a look at this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx How to link servers.

Comment: nevermind, I just found out that I can't reference other databases on SQL Azure :\

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fully qualify column names in select, insert, or update statements if you use table aliases. So, you might do something like:

```
INSERT INTO A.dbo.R SELECT C.id <[,...]> FROM S.B.dbo.R AS C
```

You can't use a "5-part identifier" in the select clause.